# How to validate a login form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Can anyone please tell me how to validate a login form with the jQuery Validate plugin?

I tried this code:

```
    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="loginbut/js/login.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#loginform").validate({
rules:{
//name:"required",
username:"required",

password:"required",
gender:"required",

},
messages:{
email:"This field cannot be empty",

password:{
required:"specify password",

},

});

});


</script>
```

and html code as:

```
<div id="bar">
    <div id="container">
        <!-- Login Starts Here -->
        <div id="loginContainer">
            <a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>Login</span><em></em></a>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div id="loginBox">                
                <form id="loginForm">
                    <fieldset id="body">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="email">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required"/>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"/>
                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" />
                        <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Remember me</label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Login Ends Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Validation is not working.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because you have a multitude of syntax and formatting errors.  The `validate()` plugin uses the `name` attribute on `input` fields.  Your two fields are using `email` and `password` for their `name` `attribute`.  I don't even know why your function contains `gender`, because it's not contained in your HTML anywhere that I can see.

Your code has many problems:

- missing a closing brace, `}`
- you do not have a field named `"gender"`, so I removed this rule.
- `username:"required",` is not typical format for this rule.  Should be `required: true,`
- improperly targeting `"username"` when the field's `name` attribute is `"email"`
- you misspelled `#loginForm` in your jQuery code
- you do not need `class="required"` in the `input` if you're going to specify rules within the jQuery, so remove that from your HTML.
- many "trailing commas" removed which will cause issues in certain versions of Explorer

**Just a tip:** Many of your syntax errors would be much easier to spot when the code is properly indented.

Assuming the HTML of your `form` is correct, your **jQuery** should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#loginForm").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "specify email"
            },
            password: {
                required: "specify password"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/fYdkL/1/**

---

**Documentation:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

**Official Examples:**

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: Thank you so much..I have corrected my errors.
it's working perfectly now.