# how to validate a radio button and add alphanumeric property to text box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I tried this code to validate radio buttons:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myform").validate({
rules:{
username:{
required:true,
alphanumeric:true
}
gender:"required",
},
messages:{
username:
{
required:"username cannot be empty",
alphanumeric:"username needs to be alphanumeric"
}
gender:{
required:"specify this field",
}
}
});
});


</script>
<style type="text/css">


label.error
{
color:red;
padding-left:.5em;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="r.html">
<table>

<tr>
<td><label for="username">Username<em>*</em>:</td></label><td><input type="text"           id="username" name="username"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="gender" validate="required:true" class="required">Gender<em>*</em>:      </label></td><td><input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male"/>Male</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female"/>Female</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I tried this code, gender field is being validated but error message is appearing in-between gender and male attributes..but it must appear `0.5em` after male attribute.

and alphanumeric validation is not working at all.
please someone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multitude of errors....

---

Just like [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171179/how-to-validate-a-login-form-with-jquery), this is not the typical syntax for a rule...

```
gender:"required",
```

It should be `required: true` and inside of your `rules: {}` like this...

```
rules: {
    username: {
        required: true,
        alphanumeric: true
    },
    gender: {
        required: true
    }
},
```

In your HTML here...

```
<label for="gender" validate="required:true" class="required">Gender<em>*</em>:</label>
```

`validate="required:true"` is totally superfluous and should be removed.

- It's meaningless as it's a totally fabricated `attribute`.
- It's applied to the `label` instead of the `input`.

`class="required"` is not only superfluous since it's applied to a `label` and not an `input` element, it's totally redundant because you're already specifying the rule within your `.validate()` options.

With the rule defined in your jQuery, the HTML would simply be:

```
<label for="gender">Gender<em>*</em>:</label>
```

---

To use the `alphanumeric` rule, you need to also include the *"additional methods"* file [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/):

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.js

or minified:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.min.js

---

You have invalid HTML here.  Note how `</label>` wraps outside the `</td>`...

```
<td><label for="username">Username<em>*</em>:</td></label>
```

Should be:

```
<td>
    <label for="username">Username<em>*</em>:</label>
</td>
```

---

As far as placing your errors, I would not have used a `table` for laying out the form in the first place.  Be that as it may, you could place the error messages using the built-in `errorPlacement:` method.  `error.insertAfter(element)` is the default function.

Using conditionals to test the type of `input` will allow you to change this function for the radio buttons.  You can tweak the code below to place your messages as desired.

**jQuery `.validate()` method:**

```
$("#myform").validate({

    // your rules and options,

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is('input[type="text"]')) {
            error.insertAfter(element); // placement of errors on text fields
        } else if (element.is('input[type="radio"]')) {
            element.next('.radio-message').html(error);  // placement of errors on radio buttons
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);  // default placement
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" />Male <span class="radio-message"></span>
```

**Working Demo:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/kP4Xy/**

---

You were also missing a comma (***will*** break code) and had some extra commas (*might break code in IE*).

Again, **[like I stated before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14175055/594235), when you follow proper code indentation and formatting, it's much easier to see these mistakes.**  *I strongly suggest you take my advice this time.  You will become a better programmer, your code will be easier to read, your HTML will be more valid, and your JavaScript will be easier to troubleshoot.*

---

**Plugin Documentation:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation